# Ember: using an #if helper in a component

Tags: ember.js

Obviously super new to Ember. Couldn't find an example of what I'm looking to do in docs.
Anyway, I have some code like this:

```
    {{#if (eq type 1)}}
        <span>
             {{convert-type measurement showUnits=true myUnits=myUnits}} 
        </span>
    {{else}}
        <span>{{convert-type measurement showUnits=true}}</span>
    {{/if}}
```

And it seems pretty verbose. I want to do something like:

```
<span>
     {{convert-type 
      measurement
      showUnits=true 
      (if (eq type 1) myUnits=myUnits) }}
</span>
```

But I keep getting template errors. :/ Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If think better method is to use computed property:

```
myUnitsPrim: computed('type', 'myUnits.[]', function() {
  return this.get('type') === 1 ? this.get('myUnits') : null;
})
```

and then

```
{{convert-type 
      measurement
      showUnits=true 
      myUnits=myUnitsPrim }}
```

or just:

```
{{convert-type 
      measurement
      showUnits=true 
      myUnits=(if (eq type 1) myUnits null) }}
```